# OpenCV cv2.fillPoly vs. cv2.fillConvexPoly: expected data type for array of polygon vertices?

Tags: python, opencv

I have the following code:

```
import cv2
import numpy

ar = numpy.zeros((10,10))
triangle = numpy.array([ [1,3], [4,8], [1,9] ], numpy.int32)
```

If I use cv2.fillConvexPoly like so:

```
cv2.fillConvexPoly(ar, triangle, 1)
```

then the results are as expected.  If, however, I try:

```
cv2.fillPoly(ar, triangle, 1)
```

then I get a failed assertion.  This seems to be identical to the assertion that fails if I use a numpy array for `cv2.fillConvexPoly` that does not have dtype `numpy.int32`.  Do `cv2.fillPoly` and `cv2.fillConvexPoly` expect different data types for their second argument?  If so, what should I be using for `cv2.fillPoly`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`cv2.fillPoly` and `cv2.fillConvexPoly` use different data types for their point arrays, because `fillConvexPoly` draws only one polygon and `fillPoly` draws a (python) list of them.  Thus,

```
cv2.fillConvexPoly(ar, triangle, 1)
cv2.fillPoly(ar, [triangle], 1)
```

are the correct ways to call these two methods.  If you had `square` and `hexagon` point arrays, you could use

```
cv2.fillPoly(ar, [triangle, square, hexagon], 1)
```

to draw all three.

Comment: What is the 1 stand for? Color?

Comment: At the time I think it was color, but I haven't used OpenCV in >5y, so I'd definitely check updated documentation and test it to be sure.

Comment: @RoiMulia yes it's the color

Comment: @NimrodMorag Thanks! Out-of-the-blue, will you be interested to consult to my company for CV related stuff?