# TypeError: Scalar value for argument 'color' is not numeric in openCV

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

Here is my code

```
im = cv2.imread('luffy.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,0)

contours,h = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for cnt in contours:
    moment = cv2.moments(cnt)
    c_y = moment['m10']/(moment['m00']+0.01)
    c_x = moment['m01']/(moment['m00']+0.01)
    centroid_color = im[c_x,c_y]
    centroid_color = np.array((centroid_color[0],centroid_color[1],centroid_color[2]))
    print type(centroid_color)
    cv2.fillPoly(im,cnt,centroid_color)
```

I am getting that error on the last line where I try and pass centroid_color into the color argument. It is `<type 'numpy.ndarray'>` and I have been able to successfully pass this data type into cv2.fillPoly as the color in other instances, so I am not sure why it is having a problem here.

Comment: as for opencv 4.7, np.ndarray is not acceptable as color iterable, try:
`cv2.fillPoly(im,cnt,centroid_color.tolist())`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fillPoly()` expects an iterable, i.e. put the cnt in brackets. I believe it is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/17582850/5818240.

Moreover, your `centroid color` variable contains strings. You need to convert them to integers.

`centroid_color = np.array((int(centroid_color[0]),int(centroid_color[1]),int(centroid_color[2])))`

Comment: ill check that one out. Putting cnt in brackets did not change/fix the error

Comment: I see, there is something wrong with `centroid_color`. Do `np.array((int(centroid_color[0]),int(centroid_color[1]),int(centroid_color[2])))`

Answer (score 8):

> centroid_color = tuple ([int(x) for x in centroid_color])

Comment: Please [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55470272/edit) some explanation to your answer